# Using CSS to offset the start of a background

Tags: css, html

I am attempting to make a sidebar for a tumblr page have a curved header and the rest of the sidebar be squared with 100% height so it flows off the "page" with no visible footer. I have layered backgrounds and as you might expect the square background with current coding is going to show at the top of the curve removing the transparent affect I want at the top.

[This is the live preview.](http://xtheme004.tumblr.com/)

Here is the coding used for those side bars:

```
    #left, #right {
            background-image: url('http://static.tumblr.com/gxcukg0/VOFn4jkk6/bg-sidehead.png'), 
                url('http://static.tumblr.com/gxcukg0/6SUn4jkk3/bg-side.png');
            background-repeat: no-repeat, repeat-y;
            background-color: #b8a6a5;
            position: absolute;
            min-height: 100%;
            top: 0px;
            width: 345px; }
```

Is there a way of accomplishing my goal without making a separate div for the top of each side?

Comment: looking for `background-position`

Comment: Thank you! I am attempting to play with that now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get this to work, you need to use the `:before` selector:

```
#left:before, #right:before{
    height: 100px;
    width: 345px;
    background-image: url('http://static.tumblr.com/gxcukg0/VOFn4jkk6/bg-sidehead.png');
    position: absolute;
    top: -100px;
    content: " ";
}

#left, #right {
    background-image: url('http://static.tumblr.com/gxcukg0/6SUn4jkk3/bg-side.png');
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
    position: absolute;
    min-height: 100%;
    top: 100px;
    width: 345px;
}
```

Note that I've bumped down the main divs with `top: 100px;`, bumped up the `:before` part with `top: -100px;`, and moved the header background image to the `:before`.

Comment: Thank you! I corrected the width on left,right to 345, and added a comma between left:before and right:before but otherwise this works as intended!

Comment: D'oh, forgot about that comma, I was only working on the left one in the debug console and had to add the right one when I posted it. No idea where that other width value came from. Fixed for future users.

Answer (score 1):

Oki doki the best way for you to do this would be to use the css style background-position. 
For example

```
img {
  background-position :-10px 0px;
}
```

The above with offset the image by - 10px to the left and 0px to the top.

I hope that helps!

Comment: I've tried updating the code to the following:
        background-position: top, 0px 200px 0px 0px; 

But the result is unsuccessful. I can move it to the left or right but I'm still having trouble offsetting it on the y-axis, which I feel might be attributed to the repeat-y. Is there another work around or an error in my code?

Comment: Okay so first get rid of the no-repeat and then background-position should just be background-position:0px 15px as such let me know if that's works

Comment: The no-repeat is based on the curved portion of the background. I'm attempting to offset the other one, which appears to be something I'm unable to do and also repeat the background on the y-axis.